# can I use contains function in mysql 4.0.27?

Tags: sql, mysql

i run this sql in mysql 4.0.27:

```
select * from table where contains(name,"foo");
```

report a syntax error, why?

can I using contains function in mysql 4.0.27?

thanks for help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I doesn't look like `CONTAINS()` is a MySQL function, but you can use the [`INSTR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/string-functions.html#function_instr) function in MySQL 4.0 as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE INSTR(name, 'foo') > 0;
```

You can also use the [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) operator:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%foo%';
```

However keep in mind that such queries would not use an index on the `name` field if one exists.

Comment: thanks! how to implement "OR","AND" in instr? `INSTR(name, 'foo OR koo') > 0`  like this

Comment: @Zenofo: No, you'll have to repeat the function: `WHERE (INSTR(name, 'foo') > 0) OR (INSTR(name, 'koo') > 0)`... Note that you can also use `WHERE name LIKE '%foo%' OR name LIKE '%koo%'`.